# How to use SEQUENCE in Apache Derby?

Tags: java, sql, sequence, derby

I'd like to use SEQUENCE support in Apache Derby 10.7. I've created the sequence with the following statement:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SAMPLE_SEQ AS INT MAXVALUE 999999 CYCLE;
```

How can I select next/current value from the `SAMPLE_SEQ`? Could you please help me out with the query?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apache Derby Doc says: [Use a NEXT VALUE FOR expression](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.6/ref/rrefsqljnextvaluefor.html#rrefsqljnextvaluefor)

Should be something like

```
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR SAMPLE_SEQ;
```

Comment: Derby complains about the query you've suggested. It doesn't like premature ending of the query (EOF). What works for me is `VALUES NEXT VALUE FOR SAMPLE_SEQ`

Comment: @pregzt - that was my concern - I didn't find a working example for a query to get a single value from a sequence - the fragment was used *inside* a more complex query...

Comment: Why was this upvoted when it doesn't work? Please could someone edit the SQL to make it work?

Comment: Here is SQL that actually works: "select next value for SAMPLE_SEQ from (values 1) t".

Answer (score 3):

Use NEXT VALUE FOR as documented in the manual:

http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/ref/rrefsqljnextvaluefor.html#rrefsqljnextvaluefor

Answer (score 1):

To get the current value of the sequence the following SQL should be executed:

```
SELECT CURRENTVALUE FROM SYS.SYSSEQUENCES WHERE SEQUENCENAME='SAMPLE_SEQ'
```

Comment: That is not the current value.

Comment: Querying `SYSSEQUENCES` can cause concurrency issues.  Derby provides the built-in system function `SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_PEEK_AT_SEQUENCE` to read the next number from the sequence generator; see the [Derby Ref Guide](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.14/ref/rrefsyscspeeksequence.html) and [Derby Tuning Guide](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.14/tuning/ctunperfsequences.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

In the SQL command prompt, you can query the next value with this statement:

```
values NEXT VALUE FOR <sequence_name>
```

This will work as an expression embedded into an INSERT statement. E.g.:

```
INSERT INTO <table_name> (IDFIELD) VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR <sequence_name>)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to fetch the 'current value' from the 'sequence':

- **values ( next value for <*sequence*> )**

Same in Java using JDBC:

```
ResultSet rs = conn.prepareStatement("values (next value for <sequence>)").executeQuery();
rs.next();
int seqValue = rs.getInt(1);
```

Source:
[Derby-user-mailing list archive](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/db-derby-user/201201.mbox/%3CCA+fW5=cLnOOOtxt0-cQp2pdHBo=3Z8dhfXd3L16=EikgVPRfsg@mail.gmail.com%3E)

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL returns the next value of a SEQUENCE in Derby:

```
select next value for SAMPLE_SEQ from (values 1) t
```

The part "(values 1) t" makes a table with 1 row and 1 column, which then gets substituted with the next value from the sequence.   In Oracle you can use the standard DUAL table, and in other databases you can execute SELECT without a table.