# embedded apache derby sequence

Tags: java, derby

I have created a sequence in apache derby:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE app.patient_id_seq AS BIGINT START WITH 100000 INCREMENT BY 1;
```

I am getting next sequence value in derby console -

```
values NEXT VALUE FOR patient_id_seq;
```

But when I use it in java code to get next sequence it says -

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: SEQUENCE 'APP.PATIENT_ID_SEQ' does
>   not exist
>
> 17:52:50,291 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown
>   Source)
>
> 17:52:50,301 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
>
> 17:52:50,312 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown
>   Source)
>
> 17:52:50,323 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown
>   Source)
>
> 17:52:50,336 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown
>   Source)
>
> 17:52:50,347 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown
>   Source)
>
> 17:52:50,357 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.(Unknown
>   Source)
>
> 17:52:50,371 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.newEmbedPreparedStatement(Unknown
>   Source)
>
> 17:52:50,382 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown
>   Source)
>
> 17:52:50,397 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown
>   Source)
>
> 17:52:50,408 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   com.laput.dao.PatientDAO.savePatientDetails(PatientDAO.java:30)
>
> 17:52:50,420 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   com.laput.dao.PatientDAO.savePatientInfo(PatientDAO.java:21)
>
> 17:52:50,431 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   com.laput.controller.HospController.login(HospController.java:66)
>
> 17:52:50,443 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>
> 17:52:50,454 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>
> 17:52:50,465 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>
> 17:52:50,477 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>
> 17:52:50,491 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
>
> 17:52:50,509 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
>
> 17:52:50,522 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
>
> 17:52:50,535 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
>
> 17:52:50,552 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
>
> 17:52:50,566 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>
> 17:52:50,579 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
>
> 17:52:50,591 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
>
> 17:52:50,606 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>
> 17:52:50,618 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
>
> 17:52:50,629 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
>
> 17:52:50,640 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>
> 17:52:50,657 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
>
> 17:52:50,669 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)
>
> 17:52:50,685 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
>
> 17:52:50,697 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
>
> 17:52:50,711 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)
>
> 17:52:50,723 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
>
> 17:52:50,735 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145)
>
> 17:52:50,747 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
>
> 17:52:50,767 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)
>
> 17:52:50,780 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336)
>
> 17:52:50,792 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:488)
>
> 17:52:50,803 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpProtocol.java:420)
>
> 17:52:50,816 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920)
>
> 17:52:50,827 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
>
> 17:52:50,838 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1) Caused
>   by: ERROR 42X94: SEQUENCE 'APP.PATIENT_ID_SEQ' does not exist.
>
> 17:52:50,849 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown
>   Source)
>
> 17:52:50,864 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown
>   Source)
>
> 17:52:50,875 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.NextSequenceNode.bindExpression(Unknown
>   Source)
>
> 17:52:50,886 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.ValueNode.bindExpression(Unknown
>   Source)
>
> 17:52:50,898 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.ResultColumn.bindExpression(Unknown
>   Source)
>
> 17:52:50,911 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.ResultColumnList.bindExpressions(Unknown
>   Source)
>
> 17:52:50,924 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.RowResultSetNode.bindExpressions(Unknown
>   Source)
>
> 17:52:50,935 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-1)  at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DMLStatementNode.bindExpressions(Unknown
>   Source)

====================

My java code to get sequence -

```
        ResultSet rs = conn.prepareStatement( "values  next value for patient_id_seq").executeQuery();
```

thanks,
laput

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use SEQUENCE in Apache Derby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729063/how-to-use-sequence-in-apache-derby)

Comment: Okay, the duplicate question probably doesn't help you much because you already seem to be using the correct syntax for getting the sequence value. Are you sure that the sequence is actually created -- and that you're connecting to the correct DB?

Comment: Can you create a minimal test case to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: OP here. Yes i am connecting to the same DB as sequence.

Comment: Yes, I am connecting to same DB and the sequence is created. I can get sequence number when queried from DC prompt. Problem is from java side.

Answer (score 0):

OP here again,
Also, tried creating sequence within DB with -

create table patient_info (
Patient_id bigint   GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 100000, INCREMENT BY 1),
first_name varchar(50),
last_name varchar(50),
phone_no int,
address_ln1 varchar(100),
address_ln2 varchar(100),
city varchar(100),
state varchar(50),
CONSTRAINT primary_key PRIMARY KEY (Patient_id)
);

But while inserting using prepared statement, it still expects "Patient_id" to be assigned/set in java code which should not be the case.

Both approaches failing.

Answer (score 0):

Bryan,
Here is the details.

create sequence - 
CREATE SEQUENCE app.patient_id_seq AS BIGINT START WITH 100000 INCREMENT BY 1;

My code to acces sequence -

```
package com.laput.dao;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

public class Testcase {
    Connection conn = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Testcase tc = new Testcase();
        tc.createConnection();
        tc.savePatientDetails();

    }


    private void savePatientDetails(){

        try{
            ResultSet rs = conn.prepareStatement( "values  next value for patient_id_seq").executeQuery();
            rs.next();




            conn.commit();
            conn.close();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    private void createConnection()
    {

        try
        {
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance();
            //Get a connection
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:C:\\ProgramData\\tools\\apache-derby\\db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin\\hospdb"); 
        }
        catch (Exception except)
        {
            except.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   

}
```

I am able to access sequence through derby console. But from java i get the error as mentioned.

Comment: any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR SEQ_ID FROM SYS.SYSSEQUENCES;
```

You can through this query to get the sequence next value.

Answer (score 0):

the first query is get sequence name list in database.
the second query is get sequence next value .

> Oracle： SELECT SEQUENCE_NAME FROM USER_SEQUENCES; SELECT
>   SEQ_ID.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL;
>
> sqlsever： SELECT NAME FROM mydbname.sys.sequences; SELECT NEXT VALUE
>   FOR mydbname.schemaName.SEQ_ID;
>
> DB2 SELECT SEQNAME FROM SYSCAT.SEQUENCES WHERE SEQSCHEMA =
>   'schemaName'; SELECT SEQID.NEXTVAL FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
>
> postgrsql： SELECT c.relname FROM pg_class c WHERE c.relkind = 'S';
>   SELECT NEXTVAL('SEQ_ID');
>
> HirDB： SELECT SEQUENCE_NAME FROM MASTER.SQL_SEQUENCES;
>
> JavaDB： SELECT SEQUENCENAME FROM SYS.SYSSEQUENCES； SELECT NEXT VALUE
>   FOR SEQ_ID FROM SYS.SYSSEQUENCES;